# Why can I not use the 'Law of Total Probability' to solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, markov-process

[image]

In this question I tried to use the Chapman-Kolmogorov Forward equation as well as the law of total probability to solve for the Probability function

Using the fact that the generator matrix would be
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
-2t & 2t \\
 2t & -2t
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus the forward differential equation would be $P^\prime_{AA}(t) = P_{AB}(t)\sigma_{BA} + P_{AA}(t)\sigma_{AA}$

which then is $P^\prime_{AA}(t) = 2t P_{AB}(t) - 2tP_{AA}(t)$

now using the fact that $P_{AA}(t)= 1-P_{AB}(t)$ then, $P_{AB}(t)= 1-P_{AA}(t)$

we can rewrite the forward differential equation as $P^\prime_{AA}(t) = 2t(1-P_{AA}(t)) - 2tP_{AA}(t)$

Solving this differential equation using the Integrating factor method gives me a solution which is not the same as the one provided. With my method I get $P_{AA}(t)=\frac {e^{-2s^2+C}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$. Using the given fact that $P_{AA}(0)=1$, I then get $1=1$.

The solution provided is that the result is the occupancy probability
$P_{AA}(t)= P_{\overline AA}(t))=e^{-s^2}$

I am not sure why my method didn't work when it should work as there are only 2 states. Any help is appreciated and sorry if this question is extremely basic and if my formatting is bad (first time posting a proper question).

ALSO If someone can help explain part B to me that would be much appreciated thank you.